# Need to Build a specific response matrix such as the response will be Symmetric

Tags: matlab

Good day stackoverflow,
not on my work computer so i can't provide code with my question, but i'll try to be explicative.

I need to create a m x m matrix that forces an optimization function(fminsearch in this case) to give a symmetrical response.

So what I want to have is **X**=[*x*(1) *x*(2); *x*(2) *x*(3)], but i need the program to build that matrix automatically given only the dimension m.

I managed to get the right numbers in the right positions, but i can't pass them as indexes. Tried as cells and as strings, but still no luck.

I want to have an *x*(1:max(max(X))) sorted as **X** above in order to feed it to the optimization program

That OR a way to make an optimization function give a symmetric answer.

Comment: What do you mean by the response of `fminsearch` being symmetric, exactly?

Comment: i want the minimun with a constraint of it being a symmetrical matrix